# SCIP jni basic questions

Tags: scip

I am quite new to [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de). I want to use the branch-and-price framework of SCIP, just like the Bin packing problem in the example file. May I ask if it is possible?

When I read the jni example file, what is the mean of this function:

```
env.readProb(scip, "data/test.lp", "")
```

It seems read in a LP file, but how can I get this file initially? Also the

```
env.readSol(scip, "data/solution.sol")
```

function, do I need to first use some solvers to generate these two files?

Best regards,
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a thorough look at the [documentation](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/) of SCIP first. I, also don't recommend to start with the JNI. You may be better of with the Python interface that is also included in SCIP.

SCIP is a solver. If you don't have a problem to solve, e.g. `test.lp`, what do you intend to do with it?

[`readProb()`](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/scip_8h.php#af86148a97b0123d44562de425346a4c7)

[`readSol()`](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/scip_8h.php#a981a12aa8af0e393e1bb370a15880427)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I plan to solve a VRP kind of problem, slightly different from the traditional VRP, each vehicle has different cost function, together with driver working hour and capacity constraints. To solve the problem, I recheck the SCIP examples, which example should I start: the VRP example or the Binpacking example? It seems the VRP one donot have the branch_ryanfoster part, and the Binpacking example is far different from my problem.

Comment: Since you will have to write some new code it never hurts to have a look at both examples. Using the VRP as starting point for your project seems reasonable. Please consider marking this question as "solved" as there will likely be no further or more precise/helpful answers.